# CSS - Darken image except for rectangle overlay

Tags: html, css, image

I have an `<img>` for which I want to highlight a certain area as shown below:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out a way to create the following effect using just CSS and no JS. I was originally thinking of using an inset border-box, but I need to be able to use percentages for both the location (e.g. top left of the highlighted area is 50% in from left and 80% down from right) and size of box and it appears that `border-box` can only take px values. I could use JS to keep resizing everything if the image size changes, but I don't want to do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: I dont think something like this is possible with bare css (I tried something similar before...). However, you can just e.g. create a class (does javascript have classes?) or something similar that you could just use to create something like a `HighlightedImage` that comes with the resizing code and does not require any complicated initialization.

Comment: Well if I have to rely on JS I know how to do this..I just really don't want to as I don't like having a ton of stuff run each time the window resizes. I'd like the CSS to handle it all.

Comment: Well, the problem is that what you are trying to do is something about the "logic" of the image (highlight a specified part within the image) which is not what css is intented to do (as CSS is about the look of things). Also, using efficient code, or e.g. by delaying resizing if many calls occur, you can minimize the effort the computer has to do. Another solution would be to create an image that is already highlighted server-side with PHP (your task doesnt look like it needs dynamic highlighting)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create one `div` element with `img` inside. And then use `pseudo-element` on `div` that will have large `box-shadow`, and you can position pseudo-element using `position-absolute`

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 2000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/ff/00/5e/ff005e0fa600c51c5e36f6059bbe6053.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: I almost posted the same solution though I backed off because of the requirement for the box width and height to be based on percentages. What would you suggest to do for this?

Comment: I think it works though with percentages..doesn't it?

Comment: Yes and its relative to `div` or parent size which when you use `display: inline-block` becomes image size

Comment: Right on. I must have had a property missing or set to the incorrect value as the percentage height wasn't working for me. But it clearly does here.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try creating 4 boxes positioned all sides of the image overlapping as much as you need. Set the boxes color to black with a transparency, and adjust the sizes of them how you like. These boxes would sit ontop of the original image.

Comment: And make sure the boxes overlap a little so that page zooming doesn't create little slivers of full-color image.

Comment: I was thinking about that too - it seems a little cumbersome but it might work, the problem is won't the corners where two boxes overlap be extra dark? I don't want that.

Comment: @abagshaw Ya it's possible that might happen. I have never tried this, it was just an idea.